# Apache NiFi: Creating new column using a condition

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have asked a similar question. Yet I wasn't able to find a solution for my problem through that approach. I have a csv which looks like this:

```
studentID,regger,age,number
123,west,12,076392367
456,nort,77,098123124
231,west,33,076346325
```

I want to add a new column and add values according to the data in the number field.This is the logic.

`If the first 4 digits of data in the number column is equal to "0763" then the new column named (status) must be set as INSIDE or if it is any other value its OUTSIDE`

As mentioned in the logic the output must look like this:

```
studentID,regger,age,number,status
123,west,12,076392367,INSIDE
456,nort,77,098123124,OUTSIDE
231,west,33,076346325,INSIDE
```

**My Approach**

I tried to achieve this by first duplicating the number column to the status column. And then trying to take the first 4 digits and dealing with it.

Hope you would be able to suggest a way to Nifi Workflow to make this possible.

Comment: You do not need to split the record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the `UpdateRecord` processor twice and got the results that you want.

**Input**

I started with your input data.

```
studentID,regger,age,number
123,west,12,076392367
456,nort,77,098123124
231,west,33,076346325
```

**Process**

First, set the `UpdateRecord` processor as follows:

```
Record Reader               CSVReader
Record Writer               CSVRecordSetWriter
Replacement Value Strategy  Record Path Value
/status                     /number
```

it will create the new column `status` with the value of `number` column.

Second, the first output should go to another `UpdateRecord` processor with the options

```
Record Reader               CSVReader
Record Writer               CSVRecordSetWriter
Replacement Value Strategy  Literal Value
/status                     ${field.value:substring(0,4):equals('0763'):ifElse(${field.value:replace(${field.value},'INSIDE')},${field.value:replace(${field.value},'OUTSIDE')})}
```

and this will give you the final results.

Be aware that the number column is not an integer column, so you have to set the record reader `CSVReader` with the option `Schema Access Strategy` to the `Use String Fields From Header`.

**Output**

```
studentID,regger,age,number,status
123,west,12,076392367,INSIDE
456,nort,77,098123124,OUTSIDE
231,west,33,076346325,INSIDE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below logic :-

SplitText -> 
ExtractText Processor -> 
RouteOnAttribute(Add condition if first four number is 0763)

-----Match Relation--> ReplaceText(Extracted Attribute from file + "INSIDE") -> PutFile

-----Unmatch Relation--> ReplaceText(Extracted Attribute from file + "OUTSIDE") -> PutFile

Hope this will help you.